# Count Distinct Values FROM Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Written a query which returns multiple column.Out of which One Column contains repetitive entries.

```
FAULT_SHORT_NAME

ATM DOWN DUE TO LINK PROBLEM
ATM DOWN DUE TO LINK PROBLEM
ALL CASSETTES FAULTED
ALL CASSETTES FAULTED
ATM IS MARK DOWN
ATM IS MARK DOWN
```

Now I want to Modify My query in Such a way that it will show me Value Count as

```
ATM DOWN DUE TO LINK PROBLEM ALL CASSETTES FAULTED  ATM IS MARK DOWN
2                             2                         2
```

There Can be Different "FAULT_SHORT_NAME" Values so Cant Hard Code them.My Original Query is

```
      Select * From ATMStatus S Left Join ATM A on S.ATM=A.Code 
          Left Join EventMsg E On S.Fault=E.Code 
          Where A.ATMStatus=0 AND S.TicketBooked <> 0
```

FAULT_SHORT_NAME is Column of Table "EventMsg"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) since you want the values as columns instead of rows.  there are two ways to do this either a Static or dynamic pivot.

Static Pivot, you hard-code the values of the columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    Select * 
    From ATMStatus S 
    Left Join ATM A 
        on S.ATM=A.Code 
    Left Join EventMsg E 
        On S.Fault=E.Code 
    Where A.ATMStatus=0 
        AND S.TicketBooked <> 0
) x
PIVOT
(
    count(*)
    for FAULT_SHORT_NAME in ([ATM DOWN DUE TO LINK PROBLEM], 
        [ALL CASSETTES FAULTED], [ATM IS MARK DOWN])
) p
```

Dynamic Pivot, the columns are generated at run-time:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(FAULT_SHORT_NAME) 
                    from EventMsg
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,'')
set @query 
      = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            Select * 
            From ATMStatus S 
            Left Join ATM A 
                on S.ATM=A.Code 
            Left Join EventMsg E 
                On S.Fault=E.Code 
            Where A.ATMStatus=0 
                AND S.TicketBooked <> 0
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            count(*)
            for FAULT_SHORT_NAME in(' + @cols + ')
         ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Both will produce the same results. If you provide additional details about the tables and some sample data, then I could provide a more exact example.

Comment: I want to Print That Columns in Table So Basically in Format Like Select [.....],[....],[....] From ... This No. Of Column will be Dynamic

Comment: Using the dynamic version of this query will get your list and then transform it to columns with the count below it. Here is a working example of a dynamic pivot http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2fef/1